How do I make it to where my login will accept either an email or username in the username field
namespace Login
{
    public partial class logForm : Form
    {
        public logForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=testData;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True");
        
        private void logUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String username, user_password;
            username = txt_user.Text;
            user_password = txt_pass.Text;

            try
            {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM loginTable WHERE email or username = '"+txt_user.Text+"' AND password = '"+txt_pass.Text+"'";
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

                DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dtable);

                if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0) //reads dataTable
                {
                    username = txt_user.Text;
                    user_password = txt_pass.Text;

                    Form1 f1 = new Form1(); //opens window after successful login
                    f1.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect login Information, please try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txt_user.Clear(); //clears inputs after failure
                    txt_pass.Clear();
                    txt_user.Focus();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

In the string query line, it works when I just have username = txt_user or email = text_user, but it doesn't work when I try to integrate both to make exceptions for either. My main focus is to be able to use both email or username in the login field. I've tried reordering the way I've written the OR statement as well so I don't know what the answer is.

email or username = ... is not proper SQL. You'll have to do something like (email = whatever or username = whatever) and ....

Never, ever, create a database query with uncontrolled user input!

And never store plaintext passwords, you should salt-and-hash them. You are also missing lots and lots of usings to dispose.

con.Open();
String query = "SELECT * FROM loginTable WHERE (email = @usernameOrEmail OR username = @usernameOrEmail) AND password = @password";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@usernameOrEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = usernameOrEmail; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user_password;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dtable);

Parameterized query to prevent SQL injection hence the update you see in the query. And I added those parameters to assigned variables (which you declared). OR has lower precedence than AND, which fails the intended query that you were trying to structure ->
(email = 'inputValue') OR (username = 'inputValue' AND password = 'inputPassword')

To correctly check if either email or username matches, and if the password matches, you need to group the OR conditions together with parentheses:
SELECT *
FROM loginTable
WHERE (email = 'inputValue' OR username = 'inputValue')
AND password = 'inputPassword'


yes it worked exactly how you said it would, much appreciated!

Good answer, but you might wanna avoid AddWithValue, better use Add and specify the datatypes specifically as well as the value

cmd.Parameters.Add("@usernameOrEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = usernameOrEmail;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user_password;
It is a good suggestion to specify the dtypes, trimming the user-name input is a good practice. That saves the match query too. Thanks.

Cudos for the parameterized query in your answer. I suggest you improve it by avoiding AddWithValue and specify an explicit column list in the query instead of SELECT *
